# How to put #!/bin/sh into one line script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple bash script with two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
myArr=("a","a")
```

However, I need to put the script in to the yaml file, so it have to be one line. I tried
`#!/bin/sh;myArr=("a","a")`, but it doesn't work. Is there way way to do in one line?

The yaml file is used to create cron job. It looks like:

```
- name: cron for xxxx
  cron:
    name: job1
    job:  <one line script>
```

The reason I need `#!/bin/bash` is I need to use array in bash.

Comment: Please show what the final  `yaml` file should look like

Comment: This isn't possible in normal "OS" processing. The "shebang" line needs to be by itself. But *"I need #!/bin/sh is I need to use array in bash"* ... No `/bin/sh` != `/bin/bash`. `sh` has a much restricted set of features with no array processing. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks! Sorry for the typo. What I mean is `#!/bin/bash`... For `sh`, is there a way to use array?

Comment: What effect do you expect putting a script in the yaml file will have? It'll just be "data" until you deliberately subject it to an interpreter.

Comment: The shebang line is to tell the OS to invoke bash to run the commands in the script. Cannot you take it out and specify /bin/bash as the command and the rest of the script with lines concatenated to one line and delimited with a semicolon as the parameters in your yaml file?

Comment: What is the reason for wanting script code in the `yaml` file? There's something unsound about this idea. Just store the path to the script/program you want to run. If you say "oh, but it's not available on the target", then I think the "unsound" part is proven.

Comment: What's the point in doing so? Looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Start by specifying your goal, including how you want to invoke this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to put the script in to the yaml file, so it have to be one line

It seems you are jumping to conclusions here. The YAML file format alone does not force you to put everything into one line. Maybe the software that reads and executes your `job:` has such limitations, but YAML alone totally allows multiline strings

By the way: Arrays in bash are defined with spaces between entries, not with `,`.

```
- name: cron for xxxx
  cron:
    name: job1
    job: |
      #! /bin/bash
      myArr=(a b)
```

To validate this example, you can throw it into a yaml parser, e.g. https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/.

For a quick overview of all multi-line constructs, see https://yaml-multiline.info/ .

Answer (score 2):

Use something like

```
bash -c 'myArr=("a","a")'
```